# Variable errors in session for admin pages

Tags: php

I am creating a login for a website. I can get the code below working: It lets me log in! Yet I can't get a start session to work: People can still get to my pages via URL.

Log in PHP:

```
<?php
    //calling connection to database
    include "connection.php";
    //if user posts for called login
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        //declaring variables for user input and using escape string to protect php scripts
        $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$_POST['user']);
        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$_POST['pass']);
        //select from users table where user input matches un and pw
        $sel_user = "SELECT * from users where un='$user' AND pw='$pass'";
        //put content held in sel_user into variable run_user
        $run_user = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sel_user);
        //use run_user counting rows and save in check_user
        $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
        //if content row numbers greater than 0 
        if($check_user>0){
            //session where un is equal to user input stored in $user
            $_SESSION['username']=$user;
            //display admin main page
            header('Location: ../adminmain.php');
        }
        else {
            //display log in error page
            header('Location: ../loginerror.php');
        }
    }
    //close database connection
    mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Start session code which says undefined variables:

```
<?php
    include"includes/loginrequiredb.php";
    if($_SESSION['username'] !=$user){
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: view.php");
        die();
    }else 
    {
        echo "welcome to the site you have logged in" . $_SESSION['username'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: you forgot `session_start()`.

Comment: Where is session_start(); in both files?

Comment: I added session start and get:Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp1\htdocs\CRICThelpdesk\adminmain.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp1\htdocs\CRICThelpdesk\adminmain.php on line 4

    Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp1\htdocs       \CRICThelpdesk\adminmain.php on line 10
welcome to the site you have logged in

Comment: Session_start in both files not in one

Comment: And for second notice chk it is right input name $_POST['user']??? I think u r using username in HTML input or forget the name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Without starting the session you can not get the values from `$_SESSION`.

You just need to start session in your both files as:

```
session_start();
```

Note that you need to `start_session()` in both files only in just welcome file.

**Side note**:

I suggest to also use `isset()` for checking either value set or not.

Answer (score 0):

Start the session with session_start and Add a session verification file in *adminmain.php* page.

```
<?php

//calling connection to database
include "connection.php";
@session_start();
//session
//if user posts for called login
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    //declaring variables for user input and using escape string to protect php scripts
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$_POST['user']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn,$_POST['pass']);
    //select from users table where user input matches un and pw
    $sel_user = "SELECT * from users where un='$user' AND pw='$pass'";
    //put content held in sel_user into variable run_user
    $run_user = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sel_user);
    //use run_user counting rows and save in check_user
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    //if content row numbers greater than 0 
    if($check_user>0){
      //session where un is equal to user input stored in $user
      $_SESSION['username']=$user;
      //display admin main page
      header('Location: ../adminmain.php');
    }
    else {
      //display log in error page
      header('Location: ../loginerror.php');
    }
}
//close database connection
mysqli_close($dbconn);
?>




##### file verify.php #####
<?php @session_start();

  if (@$_SESSION['username']!=$user) {
     header ("location: index.php");
    exit;
  }
?>
```

Comment: thank for your comments denis I amended but still says - Undefined index: username in C:\xampp1\htdocs\CRICThelpdesk\adminmain.php on line 4 and Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp1\htdocs\CRICThelpdesk\adminmain.php on line 4

Comment: Let's see ...   Add one @ before Ex: @$user

Comment: Try session_start (); below connection.php too

Comment: well errors are now gone.... but index.php is being opened through session verify... can watch hair going grey as i work! I should of said it goes to index.php when go to url which is great but it also goes to index.php when use valid log in credentials

Comment: try if ((!isset($_SESSION['username']))) in verify.php   *edited lacked a )

Comment: <?php session_start();
       if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header ("location: index.php");
          exit;
               }
                ?>

Comment: not errors but can go to adminmain with url :( so sorry I have been going round in circles for so long with this I am obviously missing something nothing like a bit of php to make you feel stupid!!

Comment: You add include (verify.php)"; in adminmain ? Add this include 
in all pages that need protecting .

Comment: Try echo$_SESSION['username']; and verify and make sure it is recording the value.

Comment: echo username session fine shows me username as requested so it is working!! just will nto prevent users accessing page even if nto logged in so progress you are a star!

Comment: pasting  session_start(); if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { header ("location: index.php"); exit; }  directly in adminmain.php does not work ?. 
Above all

Comment: nope tried code in both verify.php calling this and also directly in adminmain.php can access through log in but also directly using url for adminmain.php.  Echo the session worked my test log in details is just test as username this showed perfectly very confused!

Comment: if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {header ("location:  any_page_out_of the_system"); exit; (Means that if the session did not start going to any page out of the system .)

Comment: I agree so it is working as not directing me to index.php just got to work out how to make it stop access just using direct url

Comment: Create a file to close the session <?php session_start(); session_destroy(); header ("location:any_page.php"); ?> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> and Try again.

Comment: would this go as an include in eg adminmain??? or in top of page with other phy to start session?